# JQuery solution for AWeber Subscriber Form - No Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aweber

How do i add some form of JQuery solution to the below code so that users are using the redirect but instead have a nice response back saying 'Thanks for subscribing'?

Also, is this the best way - The JQuery solution? Or should i try JS

```html
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1337" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="blah" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=text" id="1237" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="blah" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="First name">
<input type="text" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Your Email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

- Edit - But have it be presentable, i.e. I want to put the text within a DIV, not Alert the user with a pop up or redirect them to my page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(){
 alert("Thanks for subscribing");
});
```

#### edit   ##

[Stack overflow jQueryUI Modal confirmation dialog on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637302/4118466)